# Problems with string.replace

Tags: android, string, replace

I (still) have some problems with below scenario.
I want to replace a url link with string.replace to get it colored in green but upon executing the code it doesn`t do anything.

Example string which I want to manipulate:

```
<a class="postlink" href="http://test.site/i7xt1.htm">****http://test.site/i7xt1.htm****<br/></a>
```

I want the part between **** to turn green:

totalUrls.get(k) is an arraylist which includes these URL links (example http://test.site/i7xt1.htm).

Could somebody show me how I can achieve that?
Below is my actual code:

```
if (totalUrls.get(k).contains("test")) {

 outPut.substring(outPut.indexOf("Download Instructions:"), outPut.length());
 outPut = outPut.replace("href=\"" + totalUrls.get(k) + "\">" + totalUrls.get(k),
  "href=\"" + totalUrls.get(k) + "\"><font color='#1AB053'>" + totalUrls.get(k) + "</font>");
   }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As I understand, you are trying to set color to the current URL from someone html doc?

Comment: You seem to have missed `=` in `"href\""`, shouldn't that be `"href=\""`?

Comment: Thx Wiktor, I noticed that too and corrected it already, <font color='#1AB053'>http://test.site/i7xt1.htm</font> is being set now correctly but the color doesn`t get green.

Comment: @Sergey yes that`s correct, I need to set it BEFORE the html string gets loaded into the TextView.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by applying below code.

```
if (totalUrls.get(k).contains("test")) {

 outPut = outPut.replace("<a class=\"postlink\" href=\"" + totalUrls.get(k) + "\">" + totalUrls.get(k),
   "<font color='#1AB053'><a class=\"postlink\" href=\"" + totalUrls.get(k) + "\">" + totalUrls.get(k) + "</a></font>");
}
```